# Check Date field for empty value in XML View

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a CheckBox in my view with an expression binding and I want to check whether the OData V2 field of type DateTime is empty or not. The default value I get from the backend is `"00000000"`. How can I check for empty?

```xml
<CheckBox xmlns="sap.m" editable="{= ${!birthdate} }"/>
```

Comment: Is the Property Type `Edm.DateTime`? Or is it `Edm.String`? The value `"00000000"` is unusual for an `Edm.DateTime` type.

Comment: The property is Edm.DateTime. The field is set nullable in OData. Is this the reason maybe?

Comment: AFAIK, empty DateTime value in OData V2 is supposed to be represented as `null` in JSON format. Or are you working woth OData V4?

Comment: Try with `editable="{= ${birthdate} === '00000000' || ${birthdate} === null }"` assuming the CheckBox should be editable if the birthdate _is_ empty.

Comment: Btw in your current code the `!` should be before the value and not before the path. `{= !${birthdate} }` (may not help in this case but it's good to know the correct syntax anways).